# Conversions implied by assignment expressions

Tags: c, language-lawyer, assignment-operator

There are 2 paragraphs in the 6.5.16 chapter of the Standard:

> In simple assignment ( = ), the value of the right operand is
> converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the
> value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

and

> the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic
> type, and the right has arithmetic type;

So consider the following code:

```
float f = 1.2f;
int i = f; //error
```

Both `i` and `f` have arithmetic types so `f` should be converted to `i`. The compilation of the code produces an error though:

```
error: conversion from ‘float’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Werror=float-conversion]
    6 |     int i = f;
```

But when adding explicit cast it compiles fine:

```
float f = 1.2f;
int i = (int) f;  //ok
```

---

**So what kind of conversions are permitted in assignment expressions? I though the conversion in the Standard is equivalent to cast `(type)`.**

UPD:

`GCC 9.3.0`

Here are my flags:

```
-Werror
-Wextra
-pedantic
-Wconversion
-g3
-O3
-Wno-unused-result
-Wno-unused-parameter
-Wstrict-prototypes
```

Comment: Your code should compile. It doesn't because you've configured your compiler to treat this warning as a error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well, I didn't add the float-conversion warning flag, that's the problem.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9zqGdb7MP). What's your compiler (including version) and flags?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Added

Comment: `-Werror` means "treat every warning as a error".

Comment: `-Werror` converts warnings to errors. Your compiler is nice enough to generate a **warning** about the possible value change, you asked it to make it an **error** while in fact, it's perfectly legal.

Comment: Unrelated: why `-pedantic` for the default gcc language (`-std=gnu17`)? pedantic gnu?

Comment: @pmg I used `-pedantic` to stay in strict conformance

Comment: strict conformance to `gnu17`? `gnu17` is not Standard compliant... you may want to add `-std=c11` (or `c99` or `c17` ...) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options

Comment: You might want to remove `-Werror` and replace it with `-pedantic-errors` (and add `-std=c??`, as pmg said). Then you still get errors on conformance problems, but all other warnings don't turn into errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From gcc - wiki (since v4.3)

> -Wconversion
>
> Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. This includes
> conversions between **real and integer**

```
  14 float  vfloat;
  15 double vdouble;
  16 
  17 void h (void)
  18 {
  19   unsigned int ui = 3;
  20   int   si = 3;
  21   unsigned char uc = 3;
  22   signed char sc = 3;
  23   float  f = 3;
  24   double d = 3;
  25 
  26   fsi (3.1f); /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  27   si = 3.1f; /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  28   fsi (3.1);  /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  29   si = 3.1;  /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  30   fsi (d);    /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  31   si = d;    /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  32   fui (-1.0); /* { dg-warning "overflow" } */
  33   ui = -1.0;   /* { dg-warning "overflow" } */
  34   ffloat (INT_MAX);  /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  35   vfloat = INT_MAX;  /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  36   ffloat (16777217); /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  37   vfloat = 16777217; /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  38   ffloat (si); /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  39   vfloat = si; /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  40   ffloat (ui); /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
  41   vfloat = ui; /* { dg-warning "conversion" } */
```